# Accounting for different treatments of hover effect on touchscreen with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, touch

With a mouse on the desktop, you know that moving the cursor over will hover and clicking will click. On mobile, this is not the case. Hover is treated differently by different devices. For example, given this basic HTML

```
<div id="block">
    <div class="default">Block</div>
    <div class="overlay">Overlay'd!</div>
    <div class="click">Click'd!</div>
</div>
```

and this JS:

```
$('#block').hover(
    function () {
        $('.overlay').show();
    },
    function () {
        $('.overlay').hide();
    }
);

$('#block').click(function() {
    if( !$('.click').is(':visible') ) {
        $('.click').show();
    } else {
        $('.click').hide();
    }
});
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q4cHc/2/) for working example.

When I touch this on a Nexus 7, it'll fire hover and touch at the same time. When I touch this on an iPad, it'll fire hover on the first touch, then click on the second.

I'd like the overlays to show on mobile, so I don't want to just disable them. My solution was to set a timeout to have the hover disappear after two seconds, which worked well on the Nexus but not on the iPad. So then I sniffed out iOS to disable hover and have the timed effect fire on click.

But I know that device-sniffing is not a good solution. Also, I've learned that [you can't detect a touchscreen](http://www.stucox.com/blog/you-cant-detect-a-touchscreen/), and distinguishing a touch from a click with jQuery is probably not possible.

So, the question is: how can I detect with JavaScript / jQuery whether or not the hover and click events are firing at the same time? I was thinking about some kind of timer between hover and click firing, but you'd have to hover and click once for that to work.

In a perfect world I could either 1) detect when the hover is being fired by a touch event instead of a mouseover or 2) standardize how hover works when touched (something like `aria-haspopup` if it was universally implemented). Is there anything like that?

Comment: Use `$('#block').click(function() { $('.click').toggle(); });`. It will do both show and hide.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question...

Comment: Yeah i know it's just a tip for you .

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `touchstart` and `touchend` events for mobile devices/tablets, then detect if the touch was long (longer than 2 seconds)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/38sFs/3/)

var timeout,
longtouch;

```
$("#block").bind('touchstart', function () {
    $(".overlay").show();
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        longtouch = true;
    }, 2000);
}).bind('touchend', function () {
    $(".overlay").hide();
    if (longtouch) {
        // It was a long touch.
        if (!$('.click').is(':visible')) {
            $('.click').show();
        } else {
            $('.click').hide();
        }
    }
    longtouch = false;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
});
```

**UPDATE** FROM COMMENTS
To detect touch devices use this function and depending on the situation you wan include the proper functions:

```
function isTouchDevice() {
  return 'ontouchstart' in window // works on most browsers 
      || 'onmsgesturechange' in window; // works on ie10
};
```

Comment: This is an interesting fiddle, but if you add in a hover effect for a cursor, wouldn't the hover event still fire on mobile? Also, the idea was to have the overlay appear on touch/click and disappear, not activate the click on a long touch. Sorry if I wasn't clear there.

Comment: Yes it would, if you want it for both touch and hover then add a detection function to detect touch screen devices. I included one for you. As for the click trigger, you can easily change that I was just giving an example

Comment: Interesting... I guess I'll have to experiment some more. I was under the impression that you cannot reliably detect touch screen devices using JavaScript because some touch devices also have mice.